# How can I properly acquire an instance of the Sensor Manager or replace it with an equivalent in Android NDK?

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

I'm trying to get an instance to Android's sensor manager through the NDK.

To do this, I use the following function:

```
ASensorManager* manager = ASensorManager_getInstanceForPackage(PACKAGE_NAME);
```

When compiling I notice that the linker fails, complaining that there is an undefined reference.

```
error: undefined reference to 'ASensorManager_getInstanceForPackage'
```

This occurred very much to my surprise, since after looking at NDK header file located at
`ndk-bundle\sysroot\usr\include\android\sensor.h`, I saw that the function was indeed present.

So, believing that perhaps I was targeting an older version of the Android NDK, I attempt to use the now-deprecated function to obtain an instance:

```
ASensorManager* manager = ASensorManager_getInstance();
```

Again to my surprise, this failed as well! Instead, the compiler complains that the function is deprecated.

```
C:/Users/Nicholas/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../sysroot/usr/include\android/sensor.h:384:17: note:
'ASensorManager_getInstance' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
__attribute__ ((deprecated)) ASensorManager* ASensorManager_getInstance();
```

Even more alarming is that the compiler referenced the same sensor.h header as before and couldn't find the first function.

Why can't either function be used to obtain an instance of the sensor manager?

Necessary targeting information:

```
build.gradle

compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
AndroidManifest.xml

android:minSdkVersion="24"
android:targetSdkVersion="24"
Android.mk
```

As far as I can tell, there are no additional libraries that need to be referenced in order to use `sensor.h`, but regardless, I've included the relevant section of the Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -landroid -lGLESv3 -lEGL
```

Answer (score 1):

[ASensorManager_getInstanceForPackage](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/sensor#asensormanager_getinstanceforpackage) requires API >= 26. Check at the bottom of its documentation description.

In case still doesn't work, there was a reported issue, although seems to be fixed already:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37324654#c1